# Calculate center of a sphere based on radius, two points

Tags: c#, math, 3d

i've got a problem. I want to calculate the middlepoint of a sphere. I've got following informations:

- Point A
- Point B
- Radius

I want to calculate the middlepoint C.

How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535938/find-the-center-of-a-circle-on-a-sphere-given-2-points-and-its-radius

Comment: Not really. I dont get it with this article. Is it easier with triangle calculations?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible.

From the two points and the radius, you can determine a locus of possible positions of the center of the sphere by imagining two spheres of the same radius centered at each of point A and B. Their intersection is a circle. The center of the sphere you're looking for must lie on that circle, but there is no other information available to tell you exactly where on that circle it is.

Another way of stating this is that there are an infinite number of spheres of a given radius on which both points lie (except for the degenerate cases that the distance between the points is larger than 2r in which case there are no spheres that satisfy the condition, or exactly equal to 2r in which case there is one sphere whose center is at the midpoint of the line segment between A and B)

Comment: I just realized there is also another degenerate case: point A and B are really the same point, in which case there are also an infinite number of spheres on which they both lie, but their center could be anywhere on the sphere of radius r centered on the two points.